# Разбить массив по ; и ,?

Tags: javascript

Как разбить массив по точке с запятой `;` и запятой с пробелом `,+space` ?

Comment: Массив сплитить нельзя, толькос троку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вопрос действительно про массив:

Чтобы получить из массива строку воспользуйтесь методом [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
let str = ['a', 'b', 'c'].join('');
```

Теперь, чтобы разбить строку на подстроки по интересующим Вас стмволам используйте метод [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) с регулярным выражением `/;|,\s+/`, в котором:

`;` - точка с запятой

`|` - логическое или

`,\s+` - запятая + любое кол во пробелов после

```
let splitted = str.split(/;|,\s+/);
```

Это даст на выходе массив строк, разбитый по интересующим Вас символам.

Если из полученных строк необходимо опять получить массивы символов, т.е. формат выходных данных - это массив массивов символов можно воспользоваться функцией [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
let result = splitted.map(str => str.split(''));
```

```js
let str = ["one;", "two,", " three;", "four,  ", "  five six seven"].join("");

let splitted = str.split(/;|,\s+/);

let result = splitted.map(str => str.split(''));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "The;walrus, and;the, carpenter, walked;for a mile or so";
var parts = str.replace(new RegExp(", ", "g"), ";").split(";");
console.log(JSON.stringify(parts));
```